# C# WPF accessing my view model from my model

Tags: c#, mvvm

I'm new to MVVM and I'm trying to do a simple thing like writing a property in my class with a value from my view model.

I've got a view model which contains a value `SettingsBarWidth` (this value can be written by my view). This value needs to read by my `Bar` class.

How can I set my `Width` from my `Bar` class with the value in my ViewModel (`SettingsBarWidth`)?

ViewModel:

```
    private int _SettingsBarWidth;
    public int SettingsBarWidth
    {
        get { return _SettingsBarWidth; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _SettingsBarWidth)
            {
                SetProperty(ref _SettingsBarWidth, value);
            }
        }
    }
```

My class contains this:

```
public class Bar
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public Point CenterPoint { get; set; }
    public double Length { get; set; }
    public double Width  { get; set; }          
    public double Angle { get; set; }
    public List<Point> Points { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: "accessing my view model from my model" -  it is not MVVM

Comment: @ASh and how should I do this if I want to do this in correct MVVM?

Comment: You should pass the model to the viewmodel (constructor) and use the model in the getter and setter. Then you won't have this issue.

Comment: @bic The hard part is, my Bar object will be created in a different class, and this class is created in another class... FileReader object creates an Element object which creates a Bar object.

Comment: So wherever you create the model the next step is to create the viewmodel and pass in the model.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to approach this is to use your model as the backing instance for your ViewModel as follows.

```
internal class BarModel
{
    public int SettingsBarWidth { get; set; }
}

internal class BarViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly BarModel model;

    public BarViewModel(BarModel model)
    {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public int SettingBarWidth
    {
        get { return this.model.SettingsBarWidth; }
        set
        {
            this.model.SettingsBarWidth = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

With this you can see that the Model has no knowledge of the ViewModel and you also do not need to map the properties back.